# Elevated rights for HttpListener

Tags: azure-cloud-services, elevated-privileges, azure-app-service-plans

I have created a WCF service (wsHttpDualBinding) and published it over azure as app service. Next I created an azure web job to consume this service. When I call this wcf service (hosted over azure). It gives `AddressAccessDeniedException`. The exception log is linked here.

[exception log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2qr62zstksRenptN2w5d3loN2c/view)

I think, the issue is of elevated rights but the template I am using does not provide `.csdef` file. And Azure cloud service is not in my subscription.

Comment: You forgot to actually attach your log. Please edit your question and add the log directly to your question.

Comment: The exception log is shared here  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2qr62zstksRenptN2w5d3loN2c/view

Comment: Again, please edit your question and add the log there. Nobody will want to dig through the mess that is an external free file hoster.

Comment: Edited the link now.